# Can an SQL query select variables into different tables witn an INTO clause?

Tags: sql, sas

I'm working myself through [this guide](http://support.sas.com/kb/40/700.html) to how to convert several character variables at once to numeric using SAS. The guide uses PROC SQL, the SQL interface of SAS. What got me wondering is the part following the INTO-clause below:

> proc sql noprint;                                             select
> trim(left(name)), trim(left(newname)),
> trim(left(newname))||'='||trim(left(name))
> into :c_list separated by ' ', :n_list separated by ' ',
> :renam_list separated by ' '
> from vars;

Essentially, the clause seems to select each variable into a different table. Are you allowed to do this in SQL, or is this only a feature of PROC SQL in SAS?

I tried the syntax at several SQL sandboxes, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: This isn’t standard SQL.  You’ll have to try it specifically in SAS SQL.

Comment: No. A PROC SQL creates a single table at at time.

Comment: That is NOT writing to different datasets.  It is creating three different macro variables. I don't know of any SQL implementation that would allow writing to multiple datasets (called a TABLE in SQL speak).

Comment: Blech, that's pretty bad code, also... not what I'd recommend for doing this in SAS.  Much cleaner ways, even approximating the same actual tasks, just with a lot less code and opportunities for typos...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a feature of PROC SQL in SAS to read values into SAS Macro Variables.

Comment: Okay, but would the syntax work in ordinary SQL? If the into-clause is followed by three arguments, would it create three tables which are mapped to the first, second and third variables in the SELECT-clause?

Answer (score 2):

Only the `CREATE TABLE` clause specifies the name of the table the query should create from the result set delivered by the `SELECT` clause.

The `INTO` clause in SAS' implementation of SQL is different than then `INTO` clause implemented in other flavors of SQL.

From SAS documentation

> INTO Clause
> Stores the value of one or more columns for use later in another PROC SQL query or SAS statement.
>
> Restriction:  An INTO clause cannot be used in a CREATE TABLE statement.
> ...
> INTO *macro-variable-specification*
> < , … *macro-variable-specification*>

Compare the above with Microsoft Transact-SQL `INTO` clause

> [ INTO new_table ]
> ...
> *new_table*
> Specifies the name of a new table to be created, based on the columns in the select list and the rows chosen from the data source.

For these two the general patterns are

- SAS: CREATE TABLE *abc* as SELECT ...
- MS: SELECT ... INTO *abc*

The SAS/MS comparison for selecting a column into a variable is

- SAS (: indicates into variable)
  SELECT *expression-1*,...,*expression-N*
  INTO :*macro-variable-1*,...,:*macro-variable-N*
- MS (@ indicates into variable)
  SELECT  *expression-1*,...,*expression-N*
  INTO @:tsql-variable-1*,...,@*tsql-variable-N*

The variables the values are selected into have different scope contexts depending on system or implementation.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no method to create multiple tables with a single query in SAS or ANSI SQL.

However, this is trivial within a SAS data step using a variety of methods.

The most basic:

```
   data male female;
      set sashelp.class;
      if sex='M' then output male;
      else if sex='F' then output female;
    run;
```